# GLTF export does not respect NLA track ordering

Tags: gltf, nla-editor

Using Blender 3.3 here, been trying to export my model with the correct track ordering for NLA. for some reason, the export always messes up the ordering.

i definitely did this correctly
[image]
in the gltf viewer it shows up as this; the order is messed up the same way when i import the gltf back into blender
[image]

any ideas how to resolve this? i have to do it in this track order, the dev I'm working with won't accept anything else.

Comment: It seems the ordering is based on alphabetic order. Kindly ask your dev to use something else than this default behavior. I think you can't do too much about it only in Blender. Or put a Separating character like "A_" before your animation name. So you'll have something like "A_MyAnimationName"

Comment: Yes, it's alphabetic by the action name (not the track name), see https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/814.